# Knife zero - SSH::Exception remote forwarding request failed

Tags: networking, ssh, server, centos, knife

I have been trying to execute the `knife zero bootstrap` command on my machine but I always receive this error. To add on, I can connect directly to the target server using the SSH command.

```
ERROR: Net::SSH::Exceptionremote forwarding request failed
ERROR: /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/service/forward.rb:178:in `block in remote'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:505:in `call'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:505:in `request_failure'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:466:in `dispatch_incoming_packets'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:222:in `preprocess'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/net-ssh-multi-1.2.1/lib/net/ssh/multi/server.rb:205:in `preprocess'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/net-ssh-multi-1.2.1/lib/net/ssh/multi/session.rb:449:in `block in preprocess'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/net-ssh-multi-1.2.1/lib/net/ssh/multi/server_list.rb:47:in `block in each'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/net-ssh-multi-1.2.1/lib/net/ssh/multi/server_list.rb:45:in `each'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/net-ssh-multi-1.2.1/lib/net/ssh/multi/server_list.rb:45:in `each'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/net-ssh-multi-1.2.1/lib/net/ssh/multi/session.rb:449:in `preprocess'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/net-ssh-multi-1.2.1/lib/net/ssh/multi/session.rb:430:in `process'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/net-ssh-multi-1.2.1/lib/net/ssh/multi/session.rb:417:in `block in loop'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/net-ssh-multi-1.2.1/lib/net/ssh/multi/session.rb:417:in `loop'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/net-ssh-multi-1.2.1/lib/net/ssh/multi/session.rb:417:in `loop'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/knife/ssh.rb:280:in `ssh_command'
/home/<user>/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/knife-zero-1.3.0/lib/knife-zero/bootstrap_ssh.rb:23:in `ssh_command'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/knife/ssh.rb:526:in `run'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/knife/bootstrap.rb:333:in `run'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/knife.rb:422:in `block in run_with_pretty_exceptions'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/local_mode.rb:39:in `with_server_connectivity'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/knife.rb:421:in `run_with_pretty_exceptions'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/knife.rb:214:in `run'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application/knife.rb:142:in `run'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/bin/knife:25:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/bin/knife:51:in `load'
/usr/bin/knife:51:in `<main>'
```

I have already enabled `AllowTcpForwarding` in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file and killed all existing SSH connections on the target server before executing the command, but nothing works.

Comment: 1. Try to run `tcpdump` to check network connectivity. 2. add -VV to the knife command for max verbosity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get it work by upgrading the knife-zero to a newer version.
But I don't understand why the older version works on other environment though.